# How to merge cells of a GridPane in JavaFX through code?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a GridPane looks like the following:

[image]

I want to merge 3 columns in the center of the grid through code, but I can not find the way ho to do this. There is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227667/how-to-merge-cells-in-javafx-scene-builder) how to achieve this through scene builder, but I don't use scene builder.

Does anyone have an idea how to merge them ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`GridPane.setColumnSpan`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setColumnSpan-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Integer-) or use [the appropriate `GridPane.add` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-) to add the `Slider`:

```
GridPane.setColumnSpan(slider, 3);
```

or

```
gridPane.add(slider, 0, 0, 3, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer was covered before but the params was not clear for me, so I have add it here

```
gridPane.add(pane, 0, 0, 3, 1);
```

this will span 3 cell in the first row

```
gridPane.add(Node, columnIndex, rowIndex, colspan, rowspan);
```